# threadpool executor with for all in dict loop?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I have a program where for each in dict, thread is created with args name, dob, sex, pref. then started.

Im trying to turn this into a threadpool executor to limit the amount of threads run at once. But I cant seem to get it to work.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    for all in allList:
        name = all
        print(f'Starting process for: {name}')
        name = name
        dob = allList[name]['dob']
        sex= allList[name]['sex']
        pref= allList[name]['pref']
        a_args = [name, dob, sex, pref]
        executor.map(start_func, a_args)
```

This is how i altered it from before as you can probably tell, but all i get it it trying to start for All in my dict, not just 20 per time. I can't seem to find much about multi args except putting them in a list and this is how I had my multi threadding setup, obviously at the end i had:

t = threading.Thread(target=start_func, args=(name, dob, sex, pref))

t.start()

which works as long as there isnt too many threads. But I want to be able to handle x threads where it just cycles 20 per time

Comment: Have you tried `executor.submit(start_func, name, dob, sex, pref)` instead of `executor.map(a_args)`? I'm not a Python expert, but I would expect `map` to call the function four times: once for each member of the given array. `submit` will call it one time.

Comment: using `.map` here doesn't make sense, as noted above, you want `.submit`, and it would just be `executor.submit(start_func, name, dob, sex, pref)`, see the [example in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)

Comment: Thanks, submit works but tit doesnt seem to limit my workers? eg if there is 50 entried in allList, it sets all 50 going instantly. I have a 'pool started' print message at the beginning of start_func and they all show up immediatley

Comment: Adding: all the print statements show but it does seem to be that only 10 are running after this point, weird. Does thread start all initially but then release 10 at a time or something?